# extract table from html by position using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to extract a specific table from an html document that contains mutliple tables, but unfortunately there are no identifiers. There is a table title, however. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is an example html file

```
<BODY>
<TABLE>
<TH>
<H3>    <BR>TABLE 1    </H3>
</TH>
<TR>
<TD>Data 1    </TD>
<TD>Data 2    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Data 3    </TD>
<TD>Data 4    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Data 5    </TD>
<TD>Data 6    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
<TH>
<H3>    <BR>TABLE 2    </H3>
</TH>
<TR>
<TD>Data 7    </TD>
<TD>Data 8    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Data 9    </TD>
<TD>Data 10    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Data 11    </TD>
<TD>Data 12    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
```

I can use beautifulSoup 4 to get tables by id or name, but I need just a single table that is only identifiable by position.

I know that I can get the first table with:

```
tmp = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(tmp) ## make it readable
table = soup.find('table') ### gets first table
```

but how would I get the second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on the table title.

Find the element *by text* passing a function as a [`text` argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) value, then get the [parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
table_name = "TABLE 1" 

table = soup.find(text=lambda x: x and table_name in x).find_parent('table')
```

Comment: Just curious, why `x and`?  Surely `bool(x)` would return `True` if `table_name in x` did, no?  Are you just short-circuiting for performance?

Comment: @jedwards it's just a function argument, you can actually name it however you want, probably `text` would be a better choice.

Comment: @jedwards we are checking for `x` since it can also be `None` which would cause a `TypeError` without this extra check.

Comment: the second comment was what I was wondering about -- makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only identifiable by position, meaning it's always the 2nd table in the website, you could do:

```
tmp = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(tmp)

# this will return the second table from the website
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
second_table = all_tables[1]
```